# How to download random generated images via requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am currently rewriting the Selenium python code for requests to optimize my actions.

The website is very simple to operate, but the problem is the random generation of images.

When entering the website, I have, for example, a photo description and a photo, for example:
This is a sweet dog
Image with dog

```
<span class = "animals">
<img id = "img" src = "classes / image.php? s = 2 & amp; ts = 16669054016175" width = "350" height = "350">
</span>
```

Now, in my previous script, I saved the photo description as the title and the photo itself was saved via element.screenshot ('')

Everything worked fine in selenium, but when I want to do the same through requests, a completely different photo is downloaded than the one currently on the website.

```
import requests

.login on website with headers.
..search correct url to actual photo
... save that url from source to url variable

url = "https://www.link.com/classes/image.php?s=2&ts=16669054016175"
with open ('name.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write (requests.get (url) .content)
```

This is understandable because in the desktop version, each time you refresh the page with this link, a different description and photo appear, and I would like to download what is currently on the page, but now when i print request site source in console i see "This is a dog" but in downloaded .png is a cat photo :)

The question of how to download the current photo and the description displayed on the website and whether it is possible at all without using selenium and the screenshot method

Regards!

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be possible. Have you looked at what Selenium does differently? Maybe the source code can help you

Comment: Also I don't quite understand the problem, it sounds like the requests.get is changing the picture on the site? And why is Selenium not doing the same? Also what desktop version? I feel like there are quite a few pertinent details missing here.

Comment: @Matthias Upon entering the site, the image is displayed and Selenium takes a screenshot of it.
In the case of requests, to download this photo, I have to go to the link I provided above, but when I go to this link, the image is already different than the one currently displayed on the website. (Each time you enter the link above, the photo changes and I want to save what exactly is on the site, not what will be in the future)
So in the source in the console I see that it should be a dog, but a picture of the cat is downloaded.

Comment: okay so then Selenium is on the actual server where the website is being hosted, you have to have this code there as well then, or instead of that code. If you access the website like this it won't work. Or modify the code to not change the picture when you specifically access it.